# Why I am not able to delete my data and getting error asp.net mvc webapplication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

He guys,

I am new to asp.net MVC I am making a webapplication I am have issue with one controller name project but I have added two different view in it as HR and Accounting as well. The issue is This is basically when I try to delete a contract it takes me to "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" I need help fixig this

ContractController code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SNAPAIS.Models;
using SNAPAIS.Utils;

namespace SNAPAIS.Controllers
{
    public class ContractsController : BaseController
    {
        private AISEntities db = new AISEntities();

        // GET: Contracts
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Contracts.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(id);
            if (contract == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,ContractName,ContractNumber")] Contract contract)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                contract.CreatedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate();
                contract.CreatedBy = LoginInfo.CurrentUser();

                db.Contracts.Add(contract);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(id);
            if (contract == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contract);
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,ContractName,ContractNumber,CreatedBy,CreatedDate")] Contract contract)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(contract).Entity.ModifiedBy = LoginInfo.CurrentUser();
                db.Entry(contract).Entity.ModifiedDate = LoginInfo.CurrentDate();

                db.Entry(contract).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(contract);
        }

        // GET: Contracts/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(id);
            if (contract == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(contract);
        }

        // POST: Contracts/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(id);
            db.Contracts.Remove(contract);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Contract delete.cshtml code for view

```
@model SNAPAIS.Models.Contract

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete Contract";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Delete Contract Information</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>Are you sure you want to delete this Contract?</h4>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractName)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContractName)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractNumber)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContractNumber)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Contract create.cshtml file for code view

```
 @model SNAPAIS.Models.Contract

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Contract";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contracts", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Add Contract Information</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContractName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContractNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

                <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-default">
                    Save
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Contracts")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Contracts", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

            <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: It didn't work. Getting error "Server Error in '/' Application."

Comment: @Jolly Fix a typo. Change Contacts to Contracts

Comment: I fixed that already but when I delete it it takes me to the the contracts controller page with red cross sign next to it and in details it says this:                                                                                       SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Project_ContractId_Contract_Id". The conflict occurred in database "SNAPAIS", table "dbo.Project", column 'ContractId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @Jolly you have to post your Contract and Project classes.

Comment: Just added the contract file